# Calling function with template in function call

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading through the rapidjson library at the moment, and found this piece of code in `stringbuffer.h`:

```cpp
void Put(Ch c) { *stack_.template Push<Ch>() = c; }
```

where `stack_` is defined as

```cpp
mutable internal::Stack<Allocator> stack_;
```

and the function `Push()` is implemented as

```cpp
template<typename T>
    RAPIDJSON_FORCEINLINE T* Push(size_t count = 1) {
        Reserve<T>(count);
        return PushUnsafe<T>(count);
    }
```

My question is about the `Push(Ch c)` function defined at the top. Why is there a `template` command issued when accessing the `Push()` member function? Does it serve any purpose besides delivering clarity that `Push()` is a templated function?

Further, is this some kind of best practice / would you recommend it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: The linked answer addresses my question, thanks!
I'll let question stay as reference since it is unclear what needed to be searched for to find the answer.